# JSON Array element delete in Postgresql

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I am new to Postgres. While trying to explore JSON types got struck where i had to remove an element from JSON array. I saw postgres docs where i got only how to count all the occurrences using json_array_elements but i didn't get to remove all the occurrences.

Ex-

```
[
  {"Edgeid":1,  "OutgoingVertexid": "G",  "IncomingVertexid": ""},
  {"Edgeid":9,  "OutgoingVertexid": "I",  "IncomingVertexid": ""},
  {"Edgeid":5,  "OutgoingVertexid": "I",  "IncomingVertexid": ""}
]
```

Suppose i need to remove the array element where ever i have "OutgoingVertexid": "I".
so expected answer to be:

```
[
      {"Edgeid":1,  "OutgoingVertexid": "G",  "IncomingVertexid": ""}
]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function for that, as that makes the statements using this much easier to read (and write):

```sql
create function remove_key(p_input jsonb, p_to_remove jsonb)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_agg(e)
  from jsonb_array_elements(p_input) as t(e)
  where t.e @> p_to_remove;
$$
language sql 
immutable;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = remove_key(the_column, '{"OutgoingVertexid": "I"}');
```

---

If you don't want to create a function, you can use the query directly in the UPDATE statement:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = (select jsonb_agg(e)
                    from jsonb_array_elements(the_column) as t(e)
                    where t.e @> '{"OutgoingVertexid": "I"}');
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...Thanks for your response. Your code will work by avoiding the '{"OutgoingVertexid": "I"}' field if exists. But i am looking to remove permanently those array element which consists of '{"OutgoingVertexid": "I"}'.

Comment: @VBAGuy: sorry, copy & paste error. Just remove the `NOT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name..I used UPDATE in your query then it gave me correct result. Could you plz let me know if i could use any other method.

Comment: @VBAGuy: what do you mean with "any other method"? You can essentially put the query used in the function directly into the UPDATE as well. But if you do that a lot a function is much easier to use.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...Thanks using function gives code much readable and will be easier to debug if any issues.